# Unsupported Grant Type with CustomGrantValidator with IdentityServer 3

Tags: identityserver3

I'm trying to set up our IdentityServer solution to accept a custom Grant Validator. Our API project is accessed by to UIs, one that uses Password authentication (which is working) and now one that will use a 3rd party authentication.

In our API I've set up IdentityServer like so:

Startup.cs

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory()
            .UseInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
            .UseInMemoryScopes(Scopes.Get());

        var userService = new IdentityUserService();
        factory.UserService = new Registration<IUserService>(resolver => userService);
        factory.CustomGrantValidators.Add(
            new Registration<ICustomGrantValidator, MyGrantValidator>());

        var options = new IdentityServerOptions
        {
            SiteName = "My App Name",
            SigningCertificate = Certificate.Get(),
            Factory = factory
        };

        app.Map("/identity", identityServerApp =>
        {
            identityServerApp.UseIdentityServer(options);
        });
}
```

MyGrantValidator.cs:

```
public class MyGrantValidator : ICustomGrantValidator
{
    public async Task<CustomGrantValidationResult> ValidateAsync(ValidatedTokenRequest request)
    {
        // For now I just want a basic response. More logic will come later.
        var authResult = new AuthenticateResult(
            subject: "1234", // user.AccountId.ToString(),
            name: "bob" //context.UserName
        );
        var grantResult = new CustomGrantValidationResult
        {
            IsError = authResult.IsError,
            Error = authResult.ErrorMessage,
            ErrorDescription = authResult.ErrorMessage,
            Principal = authResult.User
        };
        return await Task.FromResult(grantResult);
    }

    public string GrantType => "myGrantType";
}
```

In my UI, I setup a client like this:

```
        var owinContext = HttpContext.GetOwinContext();
        var token = owinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "myToken")?.Value;
        var tokenId = owinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Sid)?.Value;

        var client = new TokenClient(
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IdentityServerBaseUrl"] + "/connect/token",
            "MyUser",
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyClientSecret"], 
            AuthenticationStyle.Custom
        );            

        var tokenResponse = client.RequestCustomGrantAsync(
            "myGrantType",
            "read write",
            new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "token", token },
                { "tokenId", tokenId }
            }
        ).Result;

        return Redirect(returnUrl);
```

When the Request is triggered, I get: `unsupported_grant_type`

What am I missing?

Comment: Hello. Just wondering if you fixed this and how. I am getting the same error and you configuration is identical to mine. Could you please share your solution?

Comment: danijels was correct, I needed to add a Clients.cs file (static class Clients) with a method like this: public static List<Client> Get() that returned a list of clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a client called "MyUser" (weird name for a client, but ok). Is that client registered as one of the in-memory clients with grant type set to "custom"?

Comment: Some names were changed to protect the innocent! :)